# combinations with repetitions in python

Tags: python

My task is to write a function which returns all  sequences of length n,including numbers in range from A to B,where {A1 <= A2 <= A3 <= ... <= An}.For example,if A=1 B=3 n=2 it should return [[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[2,2],[2,3],[3,3]].I HAVE to use recursion and list comprehension,and can't use itertools(I know it makes no sense).My thought was:

```
def combinations(L,len): #L is list [A,A+1, ... ,B]  
    if len == 1:
        return L
    return [[a,b] for a in L for b in combinations(L,len-1) if b>=a]
```

but it doesn't work for n>2.Could someone give me some hints?

Comment: You mean if you can't use [with_replacement](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement), right?

Comment: What do you mean saying "it doesn't work"?

Comment: I meant that lists kept nesting,as someone already pointed out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple observations:

1. If `len` is 1, you want to return [[A], [A+1], ..., [B]], and not [A, A+1, ..., B] as you have.  So you need to wrap value in its own list, rather than just returning `L`, right?
2. In the other case, when `len` is not 1, `[a,b]` will keep nesting list, e.g. `[x,[x,[x...]]]`.  So instead of `[a,b]`, use `[a]+b`.  This won't work until you fix the basis case as explained above.
3. Get rid of the `b>=a` test.  It makes no sense.  `b` is a list, so how can you compare it to `a`, and why would you even want to?
4. Instead, when recursing, don't pass `L`.  Pass it a new `L` whose members are all `>= a`.  Alternatively, you could simply use `A` and `B` as arguments and get rid of `L`.  Then you could use `range` in your comprehensions.

Comment: Yeah,you are right,thanks.I knew why my code doesnt work but couldnt find a good solution.After few corrections it works

Answer (score 0):

I cannot figure out the recursive, here is an alternative

```
#!/usr/bin/python
def combinations(L,length): #L is list [A,A+1, ... ,B]
    length_L = len(L)
    L_new=[]
    for start in range(0,length_L):
        if length > 1:
            unit_self = retrieve_unit_self(L, start,length)
            L_new.append(unit_self)
        if start + length <= length_L:
            unit = retrieve_unit(L, start,length)
            L_new.append(unit)
    return L_new;
def retrieve_unit_self(L,start,length):
    unit=[]
    for index in range(0,length):
        unit.append(L[start])
    return unit
def retrieve_unit(L,start,length):
    unit=[]
    for index in range(0,length):
        unit.append(L[index+start])
    return unit
def main():
    L = ['a','b','c']
    L_new = combinations(L,1)
    print L_new
    L_new = combinations(L,2)
    print L_new
    L_new = combinations(L,3)
    print L_new
    L_new = combinations(L,4)
    print L_new
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The result:

```
./list.py
[['a'], ['b'], ['c']]
[['a', 'a'], ['a', 'b'], ['b', 'b'], ['b', 'c'], ['c', 'c']]
[['a', 'a', 'a'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['b', 'b', 'b'], ['c', 'c', 'c']]
[['a', 'a', 'a', 'a'], ['b', 'b', 'b', 'b'], ['c', 'c', 'c', 'c']]
```